# Spring JdbcTemplate execute vs update

Tags: spring, jdbc

What is the difference between `execute(String sql)` and `update(String sql)` in [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)?

If my statement is a straight `CRUD` and not an object creation DDL (as the execute javadoc implies), does it make sense to use execute vs the seemingly more lightweight update?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The method `execute(String sql)` returns `void` if a call of the method succeeds without errors. (see [execute(..)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute(java.lang.String)) JavaDoc). As for plain JDBC, it should/can be used to define database schema elements (DDL), for instance with *CREATE TABLE...* statements.

By contrast, `update(String sql)` is typically used for DML statements which correspond to SQL INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations. In these cases, in which data are manipulated, from a programmer's perspective it is important to know how many rows have been added/changed/deleted by the respective DML operation.

For this reason, the [update(...)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update(java.lang.String)) method returns a non negative `int` value to let you know:

> Returns:
> the number of rows affected

As the JavaDoc indicates by using the term "typically" in its description, you could, however, use `execute(String sql)` to manipulate data without the need to use the returned `int` value. In theory, and for some DBMS implementations, this call could be some nanoseconds quicker, as no return value needs to be transferred.

Yet, from my personal and a programmer's perspective, you should use both operations with the difference between DDL vs. DML statements in mind, as by its nature `update` signals a data manipulation operation being conducted.

Hope, it helps.